# How to import Google library in the gradle?

Tags: android

I want to import Google library in gradle of Android Studio.

I downloaded several Google jar files like `google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev125-1.20.0.jar` and put it in `libs`, then I imported with:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

But when I synchronize the gradle, the following code returns an error:

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

How to use jar to syncronize this code? I also downloaded `google-api-client-android:1.20.0` in the libs.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these

1. File
2. Project Structure
3. Dependencies
4. Click on + (plus)
5. choose library dependencies
6. choose library then ok  again ok
7. Sync project with Gradle files.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I can't find Google library like com.google.api-client  in Library Dependency .

Comment: you have to downlaod the api and then put them under lib folder.